# Is there anything like jQuery selectors for Python objects?

Tags: python

Selectors, like jQuery selectors, CSS selectors, and XPATH are cool.

**Question** Has anyone written something like it for Python objects which are expressed as nested primitives (lists, dicts, tuples, etc.)?

(Note: If such objects need be acyclic, I wouldn't consider that too extreme a limitation for most cases.)

**Simple example** If we had data like,

```
x = [
  {'xyz': 3},
  {'xyz': 4}
]
```

then, it'd be nice if one could write something like `sel("[].xyz", x)` and get back (perhaps a reference to) `[3, 4]`.

**Second simple example** If we had data like,

```
x = [{'a': {'b': [1, 2]}}]
```

Then, perhaps we could write something like `sel("[].a.b[]", x)` and get `[1, 2]`.

Comment: maybe https://code.google.com/p/soupselect/ ... but its made to do html selects (not lists)

Comment: The closest I can think of is numpy slicing, but that doesn't have the exact power/syntax you're looking for.

Comment: This is a great question. Here's one interesting project: http://jsonselect.org. Unfortunately, not in Python yet except as a rough draft: https://github.com/gregglind/jsonselect-python.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that "jQuery selectors, CSS selectors, and XPATH" exist is because it is otherwise difficult to query the DOM, CSS, and XML.

Python, however, is generally quite excellent about providing ways to clearly and succinctly re-organize/query your data structures.

Your example, `sel("[].xyz", x)`, would idiomatically be written:

```
[d['xyz'] for d in x]
```

which is only five characters longer, and arguably much clearer. Your second example, `sel("[].a.b[]", x)`, would idiomatically be written

```
list(itertools.chain(*[d['a']['b'] for d in x]))
```

which, albeit more verbose, is less ambiguous (how do we know the lists need to be flattened in your example).

I would argue that the features you would expect from a query like language exist completely within the set of features in:

1. Dictionaries
2. List Comprehensions (and dictionary/set comprehensions)
3. List slicing
4. The `itertools` module

Comment: You're right that any such selector language would require careful design. I'm not convinced by your argument though -- obviously Python is a powerful and capable language, but that doesn't make it as concise or expressive for doing semi-structured data extraction as selectors. I.e., just because you can, doesn't mean it's as easy.

Comment: Perhaps you could design a selector language that is more concise. However, given my experience with XPATH, I would mourn anything that replaced list comprehensions. I have yet to see a language feature that has a higher understandable to conciseness ratio when it comes to selecting data.

Comment: That being said, if you want to persist semi-structured data with python, and query it using something akin to XPATH, there's any easy way to do that. Persist the data as xml, and use XPATH through `lxml`: http://lxml.de/.